# Camera switching mechanism

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, camera, indexoutofrangeexception

As a part of my research project, I have been testing a camera switching mechanism.

There are two things that I have been able to notice so far with the code below. Before I applied this code, the Main Camera was shown by default. However, now the last camera is shown by default, and even when I disable the script, I am unsure as to how I will fix this issue. Additionally, the code below throws an ArrayIndexOutofRangeException at line 46 in cameras[currentCameraIndex - 1].enabled = false; inside the else clause.

Do any of you guys possibly know what is going on and how I can solve it?

Thank you so much!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
public Camera[] cameras;
private int currentCameraIndex;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    currentCameraIndex = 0;

    //Turn all cameras off, except the first default one
    for (int i = 1; i < cameras.Length; i++)
    {
        cameras[i].enabled = false;
    }

    //If any cameras were added to the controller, enable the first one
    if (cameras.Length > 0)
    {
        cameras[0].enabled = true;
        Debug.Log("Camera with name: " + cameras[0].name + ", is now enabled");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //If the c button is pressed, switch to the next camera
    //Set the camera at the current index to inactive, and set the next one in the array to active
    //When we reach the end of the camera array, move back to the beginning or the array.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        currentCameraIndex++;
        Debug.Log("C button has been pressed. Switching to the next camera");
        if (currentCameraIndex < cameras.Length)
        {
            cameras[currentCameraIndex - 1].enabled = false;
            cameras[currentCameraIndex].enabled = true;
            Debug.Log("Camera with name: " + cameras[currentCameraIndex].name + ", is now enabled");
        }
        else
        { 
            cameras[currentCameraIndex - 1].enabled = false;
            currentCameraIndex = 0;
            cameras[currentCameraIndex].enabled = true;
            Debug.Log("Camera with name: " + cameras[currentCameraIndex].name + ", is now enabled");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can `currentCameraIndex` be modified in other places apart from those two methods?

Comment: Do you modify `cameras` array in runtime or somewhere in other code?

Comment: Is your main camera the first camera in that array?  you should also add an if check in your update, to make sure you camera array is atleast 1 or more.  if you have a camera array with a size 0, then cameraIndex 0 is out of range.  It would be more helpful if you could show us your inspect that has this script, and make sure it is the only instance of this script in your scene.

Comment: @ikerbera I do not believe so, as these are the only two methods in the file.

Comment: @trollingchar no.

Comment: @Eddge I am not sure if my main camera is the first camera in the array. Inspect is coming at you ;)

Comment: @Eddge Camera 1 is the Main Camera, and it contains the script

Comment: Per your screenshot, you need to show us what is in the camera array right now we still cannot tell if the camera's are set in the array click the > next to camera's on your script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code, have just checked in unity. But i recommend you to check on press if cameras has any values

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    if (cameras.Length > 0)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```